# Error 400 Bad Request Post Request to MLFLow API of dockerized image processing onnx-model

Tags: docker, numpy, machine-learning, onnx, mlflow

For testing purposes i try to deploy the [MediaPipe Hands](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/modules/hand_landmark/hand_landmark_full.tflite) model with MLFlow in docker.
The model excpects the input `{'input_1': img}`. `img` is an 4dim numpy array `(1,224,224,3)` in `float32`
Everytime I send it, i get an `http 400 Error`.
I think its the wrong input Format, as the MLFlow API only supports

1. "JSON-serialized pandas DataFrames in the split orientation"
2. "JSON-serialized pandas DataFrames in the records orientation"
3. "CSV-serialized pandas DataFrames"
4. "Tensor input formatted as described in [TF Serving’s API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#request_format_2) where the provided inputs will be cast to Numpy arrays"

In my opinion I have to convert it to a Tensor Input as pandas only support 2 dimensions and my np array has 4dim. I tried the wohle day, but the result is still the same 400 http error:  `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: BAD REQUEST for url: http://127.0.0.1:5001/invocations`  Whole request in**5.**

**To reproduce:**
**1. Convert Model to ONNX**
As MLFlow doesn't support tflite models, I used python and tf2onnx
`!pip install tensorflow onnxruntime tf2onnx`

```
import tf2onnx
tf2onnx.convert.from_tflite("hand_model/hand_landmark_full.tflite", output_path="hand_model/hand_landmark_full2.onnx");
```

**2. Log the model in MLFlow with python**
`pip install mlflow onnx`

```
import mlflow
import onnx
import os
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

mlflow_client = MlflowClient()
EXPERIMENT_NAME = "ONNX_Hand"
experiment_details = mlflow_client.get_experiment_by_name(EXPERIMENT_NAME)

if experiment_details is not None:
    experiment_id = experiment_details.experiment_id
else:
    experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME)
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment_id, run_name="handdatasetrfrun") as run:
    model = onnx.load("./onnx/hand_landmark_full2.onnx")
    mlflow.onnx.log_model(model,artifact_path="model")
run_id = run.info.run_id
print('Run ID: {}'.format(run_id))
```

**3. I tried to access the model**
I took a random picture of my hand an formated it the way, the model expects:   [Model card](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-rmIgTfuCbBPW_IFHkh3f0-U_lnGrWpg/preview)

```
import mlflow
import numpy as np
import cv2

##read image and process it:
img = cv2.imread("hand.JPG")
#RBG->RGB
RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#224x224
resized_img=cv2.resize(RGB_img,dsize=(224,224))
#flip around y-Achsis
image_data=cv2.flip(resized_img, 1)
float_image = image_data.astype(np.float32)
im=np.array([np.divide(float_image,255)])
print(im.shape)
logged_model = 'C:/Workspace/MLFrameworks/mpHanddetection/mlruns/1/9a44d5671a6140988fbafaa939c6f9d9/artifacts/model'
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
data={'input_1': im}

#random numpy array works fine too
#data={'input_1':(np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32))}

#predict
predictions = loaded_model.predict(data)
print(predictions)
```

until here, everything works fine.
**4. build a docker image of the Model**
`mlflow models build-docker -m "C:/Workspace/MLFrameworks/mpHanddetection/mlruns/1/9a44d5671a6140988fbafaa939c6f9d9/artifacts/model" -n "handmodel"`  
`docker run -p 5001:8080 "handmodel"`
here I get some User warnings:

```
/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py:500: UserWarning: The value of the smallest subnormal for <class 'numpy.float64'> type is zero.
  setattr(self, word, getattr(machar, word).flat[0])
/miniconda/envs/custom_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py:89: UserWarning: The value of the smallest subnormal for 
<class 'numpy.float64'> type is zero.
```

**5.Error 400: Access the model via python requests:**

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("C:/Workspace/MLFrameworks/mpHanddetection/hand.JPG")
#RBG->RGB
RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#224x224
resized_img=cv2.resize(RGB_img,dsize=(224,224))
#flip around y-Achsis
image_data=cv2.flip(resized_img, 1)
float_image = image_data.astype(np.float32)
im=np.divide([float_image],255)
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:5001/invocations",   
                            data={"inputs":{'input_1': im}},
                            headers=headers)
print(response.raise_for_status())
print(response.reason)
print(response.status_code)
```

log:

```
File "c:\Workspace\MLFrameworks\mpHanddetection\Mlflow_hand.py", line 36, in <module>
   print(response.raise_for_status())
 File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
   raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: BAD REQUEST for url: http://127.0.0.1:5001/invocations
```